# how to implement Nested Map in scala

Tags: scala, oop, dictionary

I am trying to implement a nested map in scala in play framework.
what I am trying to achieve is a map which is of type `Map[String, Map[Long,Int]]`. I am not able to assign the value of the parent map which is itself a map. The application is compiling properly but the value is not getting updated. Can you please suggest what I am doing wrong and how to assign a map value to another map?

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap
import scala.collection._
import scala.collection.convert.decorateAsScala._
import scala.collection.JavaConversions.mapAsScalaMap

case class Events(eventType: String, timeStamp: Long)

object Events {

  var eventMap = new ConcurrentHashMap[String, ConcurrentHashMap[Long,Int]]()

  def save(events: Events) = {
    var eventsKey: String = ""
    var count: Int = 1
    var timeKey: Long = 0L
    var newEntry: Boolean = false
    eventsKey = events.eventType
    var countMap = new ConcurrentHashMap[Long,Int]()
    countMap.clear()

    if (eventMap.containsKey(eventsKey)) {
      countMap = eventMap.get(eventsKey) // this is not working
      timeKey = events.timeStamp
      if (countMap.containsKey(timeKey)) { 
        count = countMap(timeKey) + 1
        countMap.put(timeKey, count)
        eventMap.put(eventsKey, countMap)
      } // End of counter check
      else {
        newEntry = true
      }
    } // End of if event key check
    else {
      newEntry = true
    } // End of else event key check

    if (newEntry) {
      countMap.putIfAbsent(timeKey, 1)
      eventMap.putIfAbsent(eventsKey, countMap)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: One bug I notice with the code above, when the eventsKey is missing, you do not set the timeKey from the passed-in events instance, causing the new entry to have the default timeKey value you specify of `0L`.

Comment: Can you provide a example of what are you calling (with parameters)?  Ex: `save("aaaabc", 123323) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is happening because you are only setting temporary `timeKey` inside the if, and you still need this value outside of the if. This will make your program to always insert the first `timeStamp` of a given `eventType` as `0` :

```scala
Events.save(Events("aa", 222))     // {aa={0=1}}

Events.save(Events("aa", 333))     // {aa={0=1, 333=1}}

Events.save(Events("aa", 333))     // {aa={0=1, 333=2}}

Events.save(Events("bb", 444))     // {aa={0=1, 333=2}, bb={0=1}}
```

To fix it, just move the code out of the `if`:

```scala
...     
var newEntry: Boolean = false
eventsKey = events.eventType
timeKey = events.timeStamp // <--- This fixes it
var countMap = new ConcurrentHashMap[Long,Int]()
countMap.clear()

if (eventMap.containsKey(eventsKey)) {
  countMap = eventMap.get(eventsKey) //this is not working

  if (countMap.containsKey(timeKey)) {
    count = countMap(timeKey) + 1
...
```

Now when you run, you get:

```scala
Events.save(Events("aa", 222))     // {aa={222=1}}

Events.save(Events("aa", 333))     // {aa={333=1, 222=1}}

Events.save(Events("aa", 333))     // {aa={333=2, 222=1}}

Events.save(Events("bb", 444))     // {aa={333=2, 222=1}, bb={444=1}}
```

### Extra

I know you didn't asked about it, but I thought it would be nice to have a more idiomatic scala code:

```
case class Event(eventType: String, timeStamp: Long)

object Event {
  val eventMap = new ConcurrentHashMap[String, ConcurrentHashMap[Long,Int]]()

  def save(event: Event) = {
    val Event(eventKey, timeKey) = event

    val countMap = eventMap.getOrElse(eventKey, new ConcurrentHashMap[Long,Int]())

    val count = countMap.getOrElse(timeKey, 0) + 1

    countMap.put(timeKey, count)
    eventMap.put(eventKey, countMap)
  }
}
```

PS: I renamed `Events` to `Event`

PS2: Notice how the bug you stumbled upon is more difficult to happen when you are programming in a more idiomatic way. :)

Comment: Hello @Onilton, Thank you very much for the clarification, the code is working perfectly now. I have 1 more question it may be silly but as i am new to scala the question is: val is immutable and in the example above, the map you have defined is of type val how is it adding/updating keys and values if it is of type val shouldn't be it of type var? and thank you once again for your "extra" code which is way better than i was using .

Comment: That's because Java/Scala vars are reference variables. If you come from C/C++ background, think they are like pointers. If not, think variable are like names or aliases you put on objects.

Comment: `eventMap` is the name. You are creating a new object `new ConcurrentHashMap` and assigning the name `eventMap`. When using `var`, you can change your mind and attach this name to another object/instance (of the same type) for example, another `new ConcurrentHashMap`. This is the only thing `val` do: forbids that, the name can only be used to that specific object. But you can still mutate, call methods and change the object properties.

Comment: The best article (that explains this concept in the easiest way) I could find is for python  http://radar.oreilly.com/2014/10/python-tuples-immutable-but-potentially-changing.html . What a shame there isn't such kind of article for scala/java, but if you know a little bit of python it won't be a problem. `val` is like `final` for variables in Java, so there's also the excelent article for `final` in wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_(Java)#Final_variables

Comment: Hello @Onilton thank you very much for the clarification.